# Physical representation of the Lakes of Wada

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

While on the wikipedia page for the Lakes of Wada, it stated that an object (picture 1) was able to provide a representation (picture 2) of the Lakes of
Wada. How is this picture a representation of the Lakes of Wada?

[image: Object that can represent the Lakes of Wada]

[image: Representation of the Lakes of Wada]